# ReactJs: How to update property of state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to update the isSelected property for a row of my data stored in the state, the property doesn't update can anyone please tell me the best way to do this?

```
        var selectedIdsPush = [];
        var selectedIdsPush = this.state.contacts.slice();
        for(var i=0;i<selectedIdsPush.length;i++)
        {
            var idAsNumber = parseInt(id);

            if (page.state.contacts[i].id === idAsNumber) {
                page.state.contacts[i].isSelected = true;
                break;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reacts wants consumers to `setState` instead of assigning properties directly. In this example, we could build and assign a new `contacts` list using:

```
var idAsNumber = parseInt(id);
var newContacts = this.state.contacts.map(function (contact) {
  if (contact.id === idAsNumber) {
    contact.isSelected = true;
  }
  return contact;
});

this.setState({ contacts: newContacts });
```

Answer (score 1):

The property probably does get updated, but it won't be reflected in the UI as your app isn't re-rendered.

You could call `this.forceUpdate()` to force a re-render, https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#forceupdate.

Or more likely you should use `this.setState()`, https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate.

I currently struggle with when/where to use state as apparently it's not advised. Search for `react avoid state` for more information.